# Image does not exist

Tags: python, operating-system, docxtpl

I want to print images in word so that I can print them easier, same size, etc.
I use this piece of code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docxtpl import InlineImage
from docx.shared import Mm
import os

folder = "./mercedes/" 

for img_name in os.listdir(folder):
    doc = DocxTemplate("C:\\Users\\jpp08\\Documents\\MIDDELKOOP\\testimg.docx")
    img1 = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor=f'{img_name}', width=Mm(20), height=Mm(10))
    context = {'img1': img1}
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(f"{folder}/{img_name}" +".docx")
```

But I got the error that "name of picture".jpg does not exist. But it's the right name and right location.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Since you are iterating over the files in `"./mercedes"` you will want to prepend "`./mercedes/`" to the front of the path to the image path, otherwise it will be looking at `"./image_name.jpg"` rather than "`./image_name.jpg`". A simple `os.path.join(folder, img_name)` should be enough

Comment: Not related to your question: Microsoft Office (Word) is not known for "easy printing, same size, etc.". I'd generate a PDF from python,  (or another filetype that suits your needs), or print directly. You have way more control over the layout and print parameters.